# My heatmap doesn't work properly

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, heatmap

I have this data frame:

[image]

which contains binary values. The data frame consists of the Date column (format `%Y-%m-%d`) and the time-interval column indicated by `H01.01`, `H01.02`, ... up to `H24.06`. I would like to create a `heatmap` where time intervals (`H0.01`...`H01.02`...) is on the `x-axis` and the Dates on the `y-axis`, and for each `1`'s, I would like to fill them with a colour (In this case, I chose the blue colour).

[The dataframe is available to download using this link: we.tl/F7gJkPhStG](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/45a56d6e449be39ca51d7cb4b78e2b9f20160618204421/63fc85)

I first used the melt function, used Date as the ID.

```
dat<- melt(df, id.vars = "Date")
```

since its a large dataframe, I wanted to test it with H01.01 interval only.

```
dat.H01.01<- dat[1:146131, 1:3, drop=F]
```

and then proceeded with the ggplot function using geom_tile

```
ggplot(dat.H01.01, aes(variable, Date)) +
           geom_tile(aes(fill=value),color="white") + 
           scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "blue")
```

but for some reason, the colours won't show up:

[image: heatmap]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on your linked data and got this output:

[image]

I did change the colour gradient:

```
scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow",high = "blue")
```

White on white doesn't seem like a good idea.

It seems to work fine. Your full dataset was too large for my crappy laptop to test.

Hope this is helpful.